# Invoke ffmpeg commands from javacv

Tags: android, ffmpeg, javacv

I am trying to build a video capture application. As a reference I am using https://github.com/sourab-sharma/TouchToRecord. In this ffmpeg commands are run from "[FFmpegInvoke](https://github.com/sourab-sharma/TouchToRecord/blob/master/JavaCvVideoRecorder/src/co/vine/android/recorder/FFmpegInvoke.java)" class. When this project is run without any modification it is working as expected.

But it is using older version of JavaCV. On using latest JavaCV(1.1), build fails saying that libffmpeginvoke could not be found. In "TouchToRecord" project he seems to be using libffmpeginvoke from vine.

So my question is, can we run ffmpeg commands directly using JavaCV? Please note that in the reference project ffmpeg commands are invoked by creating an instance of [FFmpegInvoke](https://github.com/sourab-sharma/TouchToRecord/blob/master/JavaCvVideoRecorder/src/co/vine/android/recorder/FFmpegInvoke.java) in [Processor](https://github.com/sourab-sharma/TouchToRecord/blob/d8d629e89d30c1a8588f404c4f40c56dd1565716/JavaCvVideoRecorder/src/com/javacv/recorder/Processor.java) class and command is executed from process method of Processor class.

Comment: If you're using JavaCV, why not include the FFmpeg module and then call it directly?

Comment: @Edson Menegatti Now I am using FFmpegAndroid from https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java to invoke ffmpeg commands. I am not sure if this is the most efficient way since I am using JavaCV also. How can we include FFmpeg module?

Comment: I add JavaCV as follows: `compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '0.10'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '2.4.10-0.10', classifier: 'android-arm'
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '2.5.1-0.10', classifier: 'android-arm'`